# How to replace single quote with space in column in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem in updating a column in oracle which has a single quote.

The following example will clear the problem.

Lets Client name is Lucy'Mark

Now, I want to replace the Single quote with space

After output, it will be Lucy Mark

Now when I tried the following query it is not working as the query will be

```
select replace (Lucy'Mark , '''', '') from gen_clientvendor_m;
```

Please let me know the query.

I am using SQL developer

Answer (score 0):

Use the column with client name and add space to the replace statement:

```
select replace (client_name , '''', ' ') from gen_clientvendor_m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple single quotes cause headache :) so - have a look at this option:

```
SQL> with test (name) as
  2    (select q'[Lucy'Mark]' from dual)
  3  select name,
  4         replace(name, chr(39), ' ') result
  5  from test;

NAME      RESULT
--------- ---------
Lucy'Mark Lucy Mark

SQL>
```